# Connect Typescript dependency with Solidity contract

Tags: solidity, remix, exchanges, hardhat, npm

How can I connect my contract with typscript dependency (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dydxprotocol/exchange-wrappers).

I need this function (https://github.com/dydxprotocol/exchange-wrappers/blob/master/contracts/exchange-wrappers/OasisV3MatchingExchangeWrapper.sol#L69).

---

If this information is not enough for a solution, write what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In our [project](https://github.com/Arianee/arianee-abi) we used [typechain](https://github.com/ethereum-ts/TypeChain)

Answer (score 1):

I use [0xWeb](https://github.com/0xweb-org/0xweb) to generate typescript classes to access the blockchain directly

```
$ npm i 0xweb -g
$ 0xweb init
$ 0xweb install 0xab33e884ec8fed4f5867246e4300228f3d666561 --name dydx/oasis-matching-exchange --chain eth
```

Then use the generated class to send the Tx

```
import { DydxOasisMatchingExchange } from '@0xweb/eth/dydx/oasis-matching-exchange/oasis-matching-exchange';

async function submit () {
    let contract = new DydxOasisMatchingExchange();

    
    let account = { key: '' }
    let tradeOriginator = '0x...';
    let receiver = '0x..';
    let makerToken = '0x...';
    let takerToken = '0x...';
    let requestedFillAmount = 1n;
    let orderData = '0x....';

    // send the tx
    let tx = await contract.exchange(
        account,
        tradeOriginator,
        receiver,
        makerToken,
        takerToken,
        requestedFillAmount,
        orderData
    );
    let receipt = await tx.receipt;
}

submit();
```